# Test Coverage for a HttpCalloutMock?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, httpcalloutmock

We have a test class, and it has @isTest and for some reason, salesforce is showing this class as needing coverage? Shouldn't this class be excluded from code coverage?

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
global class MyMockResponse implements HttpCalloutMock{
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
         //some code
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need coverage if it is annotated with `@IsTest`. Any report to the contrary is in error. Note however that you shouldn't be using `global`.

Comment: The global thing is probably because the example in the Salesforce documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) also uses global.

Comment: I am well aware of that shortcoming.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in salesforce... The following post had the resolution. [Why are my Test Classes (marked @isTest) getting listed with Code Coverage?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/why-are-my-test-classes-marked-istest-getting-listed-with-code-coverage)

```
 1. Copy the listed test class and paste into notepad.
 2. Delete the listed test class.
 3. Create new test class with **same class name** and **same body**(structure).
 4. Finally Run the test class.
```