# Need Help for Extension Test Class

Tags: unit-test

I have a generic extention class and a visualforce page I need to write test classes against, but I am stumped.  I have tried a few of the examples found here on StackExchange, but with no luck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my classs:

```
public with sharing class ExtendObject {
private final SObject so;


public ExtendObject (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
this.so = controller.getRecord ();

}
}
```

And My visualforce page which is a controller extension:

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" extensions="ExtendObject" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tab4" id="theTabPanel" rendered="{!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c != null}">
<apex:tab label="Details 4" name="tab4" id="tab4">
<apex:iframe src="http://website.com?this={!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c}&Accept=1" scrolling="true" id="propIframe4"/>

</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Details 1" name="tab1" id="tab1">
<apex:iframe src="http://website.com?this={!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c}" scrolling="true" id="propIframe1"/>

</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Details 2" name="tab2" id="tab2">
<apex:iframe src="http://website.com?this={!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c}" scrolling="true" id="propIframe2"/>

</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Details 3" name="tab3" id="tab3">
<apex:iframe src="http://website.com?this={!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c}" scrolling="true" id="propIframe3"/>

</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Details 5" name="tab5" id="tab5">
<apex:iframe src="http://website.com?this={!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c}" scrolling="true" id="propIframe5"/>

</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? With the controller you posted you would only have to call the constructor to cover the entire thing...not much of a test case. Are there any additional methods in your controller that you need help covering?

Comment: Probably obvious, but I am a bit of a noob.  I'm not sure how to just directly call the constructor in a test.  All the tests I've written so far are for triggers so I just create the dummy data and let the trigger drive the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to check out the Salesforce reference on [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm), but here's a bare-bones test case to get you started:

```
@isTest
private class ExtendObjectTest {

    static testmethod void constructorTest() {
        // set up some test data to work with
        Custom_Object__c co = new Custom_Object__c(Name='blah');
        insert co;

        // start the test execution context
        Test.startTest();

        // set the test's page to your VF page (or pass in a PageReference)
        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.WhateverYourPageIsNamed);

        // call the constructor
        ExtendObject controller = new ExtendObject(new ApexPages.StandardController(co));

        // test action methods on your controller and verify the output with assertions
        controller.save();

        // stop the test
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried something similar earlier and I am still getting the same error:
When I call the constructor I get the error
Invalid type: ExtendObject
Any Ideas

Comment: So it turns out I needed to have the test directly within the class.  Thanks for your help.  I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Not that you're likely to run into a problem with this anytime soon, but just an FYI: adding your test methods inside a class not annotated with `@isTest` will count against your 3MB Apex code limit. It's typically a good idea to keep your test code separate from your functional code (see [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/739/use-of-istest-versus-testmethod-and-location-of-test-methods-in-classes)), but there are situations where you might want them together. But in this case, I can't see a reason you would be getting such an error when creating a separate class.

Comment: JCD, thanks for your help.  I'm a bit confused as to why I had to include it in the original class, but it IS now working.  Thanks again for taking the time to help out a noob.